# Being Paid for Preparation Time

Tags: liability

The question:
If I am missing time at work, and spending free time, to do research to free myself from a 'crime' I didn't commit, can I sue 'the plaintiff'?

The background:
A rental car company is accusing me of doing ~2000 dollars worth of damage to the locks on one of their cars, they said that I must have locked myself out and trashed the door trying to break in.

I have hours of footage of the car in the hotel lot where I parked it, pictures showing the car in the condition it was returned, and the car was inspected when dropped off. There is more information I could provide, but it suffices to say that I have mountains of incontrovertible evidence showing that I never broke the car. Three dealers have quoted me a price of ~$300 to repair the damage they are describing. In addition, they have tried to charge me twice today, once for 2000, and once for 500 dollars, and I had to cancel my credit card to prevent them from continuing to try to get whatever sum they can. I have spent the last eight hours gathering this information, I plan to write them a letter tonight, mail it tomorrow, will probably be in contact with them again at least once more, and so will be spending more of my time defending myself against a 'thief'. I have read online that rental car companies will do this sometimes, and that there is no way out of their fees, but that part I already have covered. the question is:

Is there some way for me to inconvenience them (monetarily or otherwise) to get a sense justice?

Comment: This is a site about the *law*; questions about *justice* may be off-topic.

Comment: I will note that this question appears to ask about substantive justice ("Did they get what I think they deserve?") rather than procedural justice ("Are the actions lawful?"). While substantive justice is sometimes concordant with procedural justice, it can be very subjective, and so it's important to make a distinction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking if can sue for your damages which in this case are limited to the time that you spent refuting their accusation? No. What can you do to inconvenience them? Start with yelp and go from there.